# Removing "\n" from a string depending on certain cases

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, newline

I have this string that I build using the outputs of various functions which each return strings:

```
[resource_name, 
 duration, 
 project_name, 
 total_hours, 
 details, 
 booker, 
 user_details].join("\n")
```

Each of these functions return  a string of information which, as a whole, builds a notification message. What I'm struggling to implement is each string is joined by a new line character, but sometimes the functions return an empty string, because the information isn't specified. For example if no project_name is specified, the string will be empty.

How do I make that whole line be deleted, rather than having an empty string followed by a new-line?, because that doesn't look presentable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to *prepare* the array just before performing the `join`. Consider following code:

```
[resource_name, 
 duration, 
 project_name, 
 total_hours, 
 details, 
 booker, 
 user_details].compact
  .reject { |s| s.empty? }
  .join("\n")
```

Here I used `compact` method, to remove all `nil` elements from the array (if you are 100% sure there are no `nil`'s, you can omit that one). The next step is to remove, or `reject` all `empty?` strings (please note, `empty?` is a method on `string`).

Good Luck!

Comment: since this is a basic ruby question you may just want to note that `.reject(&:empty?)` is sugar for the general form of `.reject{ |s| s.empty? }`